# How to code pthread/thread library function in AURIX TC275 in AURIX Development Studio?

Tags: c, multithreading, linker, embedded, linker-errors

I am new to coding Tricore and AURIX Development Studion. I am trying to create a thread to execute a separate function but i am not able to link the thread function.

I tried to link the thread available in include.cxx folder but i am getting the error.

cctc E205: don't know what to do with ..\AURIX-Studio-1.7.2\plugins\com.infineon.aurix.tools_1.7.2\build_system\tools\Compilers\Tasking_1.1r8\ctc\include.cxx\pthread

How to link the pthread library and to create threads.

Comment: "cctc E205" Is that literally the only info you've got? And why would you use pthreads in this kind of application anyway? They are unacceptable/unsuitable for the typical kind of applications where AURIX is used (industrial/automotive).

Comment: @Lundin, I am trying to get some data from a function present in cpu0_main for system level tests. where I need to flash the program and run the application. what happens is all the core threads access the same function and thus leading to a trap or data corruption.